# how to insert only one row using link_to_add_association cocoon gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, apache-cocoon

I am using cocoon gem and inserting a row using link_to_add_association. I need to save the row before inserting a new row.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Generally, questions should include a specific programming issue where you expected an outcome but got something else, like an error. To allow others to help you, you'll need to share [a sample of your code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and the attempts you've made so far to solve the problem.

Comment: Cocoon is used mostly for submitting a single nested object. Because your UI is getting more complex, it might be time to look into a JavaScript framework like React, so you can build a more complex UI.